# Updating a value in a dictionary inside a dictionary

Tags: python

If I have a list of contact dictionaries like this:

```
{'name': 'Rob', 'phoneNumbers': [{'phone': '123-3214', 'type': 'home'}, {'phone': '456-3216', 'type': 'work'}]}
```

how could I update this dictionary to remove the dashes from the phone numbers in a list of contact dictionaries pythonically?

Comment: Can you lead the discussion of what you've tried and how you'd like it to be improved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just nest loops:

```
for contact_dict in list_of_dicts:
    for phone_dict in contact_dict['phoneNumbers']:
        phone_dict['phone'] = phone_dict['phone'].replace('-', '')
```

This alters the values in-place.

Or you could create a whole new copy of the structure, with the alterations made:

```
[dict(contact, phoneNumbers=[
    dict(phone_dict, phone=phone_dict['phone'].replace('-', '')) 
    for phone_dict in contact['phoneNumbers']])
 for contact in list_of_dicts]
```

This creates a semi-shallow copy; only the `phoneNumbers` key is explicitly copied, but any other mutable values are just referenced by the new dictionaries.

Demo:

```
>>> list_of_dicts = [{'name': 'Rob', 'phoneNumbers': [{'phone': '123-3214', 'type': 'home'}, {'phone': '456-3216', 'type': 'work'}]}]
>>> [dict(contact, phoneNumbers=[
...     dict(phone_dict, phone=phone_dict['phone'].replace('-', ''))
...     for phone_dict in contact['phoneNumbers']])
...  for contact in list_of_dicts]
[{'phoneNumbers': [{'phone': '1233214', 'type': 'home'}, {'phone': '4563216', 'type': 'work'}], 'name': 'Rob'}]
>>> for contact_dict in list_of_dicts:
...     for phone_dict in contact_dict['phoneNumbers']:
...         phone_dict['phone'] = phone_dict['phone'].replace('-', '')
...
>>> list_of_dicts
[{'phoneNumbers': [{'phone': '1233214', 'type': 'home'}, {'phone': '4563216', 'type': 'work'}], 'name': 'Rob'}]
```

Comment: sorry stepped away, I had something like this, I was wondering if there was a way to do it with a dictionary comprehension or a single line.

Comment: @Rob: you can put the list comprehension I produced on one line. I only broke it across multiple to keep it readable.

Answer (score 1):

Just `str.replace` the `-`

```
d ={'name': "Rob", 'phoneNumbers': [{'phone': '123-3214', 'type': 'home'}, {'phone': '456-3216', 'type': 'work'}]}

for dct in d["phoneNumbers"]:
    dct['phone'] = dct['phone'].replace("-","",1)
```

Which gives you:

```
{'phoneNumbers': [{'phone': '1233214', 'type': 'home'}, {'phone': '4563216', 'type': 'work'}], 'name': 'Rob'}
```

Comment: There is a list of those `d` dictionaries, so another level of nesting is required. And they want to replace *all* the dashes, I think.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, they can iterate over the list,  applying the same logic to each dict, there is also only 1 `-` in each dict so not sure where you see the rest.